# running sequential commands on nohup

Tags: command-line

I have a process running at PID 20371 (`nohup python test.py`) it will take about 10 hours to execute, how can I run another `nohup` command when this one finishes.
i.e the process is now running I want to give a command so the VM will automatically use once that has finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have access to the shell that launched the `nohup` process, you can use the `wait` builtin. To run something after the process finishes, you can do:

```
wait 20371 && newCommand
```

---

If you don't have access to the parent shell, you can't use `wait`, and will therefore need a different approach:

```
while kill -0 20371; do sleep 2; done && newCommand
```

That will run a loop that will check if the command with that PID is still running every two seconds. When it isn't, it will launch the next command.

***Important***: there is no 100% guarantee that this will be the right process. It is possible (although unlikely) that the process may finish and its PID be reused by another process between one check and the next.

---

A much better approach for all this, and one you should get used to, is to use a demultiplexer like `screen` or `tmux` to connect to your servers and run commands in that session. That way, there's no need for `nohup` and your commands will keep running even if you log out.

Comment: thanks, what does `do sleep 2` exactly do in this case?

Comment: @hadesfv it avoids spamming the cpu.